# SQL Server Primary Key Constraint still inserts duplicates

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, constraints

Currently working on a massive data project with around 1,5-2 transactions per second.

The issue that I am getting is that duplicates are being written to a sql server 2012 db table, from a different real time component to the DB, even with primary key constraint.I assume more requests are trying to write to the DB at the exact same time. The thing is, even if there is a primary key constraint on a few tables, duplicates are still being inserted in the table. I think the trigger is called by two requests in the exact same time and checks if the row exists (at the exact same time - when there isn't any) and writes the same twice.

Do you know if this is possible or if there is any other reason for why this might happen?

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: There's no way we could answer your question with the information you have provided.

Comment: You might have to ugrade to a more robust version built for realtime work.

Comment: What does your PK constraint look like. Can you post the table definition?

Comment: If you have a formal  PK constraint, you cannot by definition get dups of the PK.  If the PK is an identity, then you also need a unique index on the natural key.

Comment: Please describe your process for how your PKs are defined and where the values come from . Are they autogenerated, generated by a process or stored proc or trigger, inherent in the data values inserted, or are you using sequences?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, there is no PK on the table. there is one SP that checks if that particular record is in there, and there is also one trigger when inserting into that particular table. I will double-check and update.

Comment: Yes, there is a customized trigger for that table (triggered when the insert is called), which checks for duplicates in that table.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement transactions in sql server. That will handle parallel insert parallel insert request properly.

Here is how you can implement transaction in sql server :

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        -- Your insert statement.
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

So when your first insert statement running and if sql server gets another insert request then it will wait untill it complete first insert statement and commit that transaction and start new one after that.

Comment: cannot implement transactions as they will generate deadlocks